# Размножить строку с увеличением числа в строке

Tags: plsql

Всем привет.
Дана таблица в которой есть число и кол-во.

```
    with cte as
(select 1 numb
        ,4 quantity
        from dual)
```

Суть задачи в том, чтобы разбить строку на количество (4) при этом к каждой строке к столбцу число добавлять единицу.

```
numb quantity
1    4
2    4
3    4
4    4
```

И по итогу должно получится вот так....
Помогите пожалуйста с решением.

Comment: Можно сделать join lateral с генератором чисел generate_series()

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS
 (SELECT 1 NUMB, 4 QUANTITY FROM DUAL)

SELECT CTE.numb + LEVEL-1 AS numb, CTE.quantity FROM CTE
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= CTE.QUANTITY
```

Если я правильно понял задание, то такое решение может подойти.